# Categorical data in sensitivity analyses

Tags: categorical-data, sensitivity-analysis

I have a model that will evaluate the carbon footprint of a product (i.e. tally the greenhouse gas emissions that were generated in each of the activities required to make, use and dispose of the product). All the amounts of materials and energy inputs and emission factors are represented by PDFs. 
I would like to introduce the uncertainty of part of the product being made from e.g. steel of aluminium. Suppose I have the following probabilities:

```
P(steel)= 0.8
P(aluminium)=0.2
```

My approach for uncertainty analysis (Monte Carlo), I simply defined a third throw-away variable `x = unif(0,1)`, and define my steel and aluminium inputs thus:

```
P(steel)=1 if x in [0, 0.8) else P(steel)=0
P(aluminium)=1 if x in [0.8, 1] else P(aluminium)=0
```

My question is about accounting for the uncertainty of material selection in sensitivity analysis (uncertainty importance). Specifically, I want to know whether it matters (from a confidence in my results point of view) that the material is not perfectly known.

I was planning on using Delta Moment Independent Measure, passing my sampled input values as input, but am open to changing approach to better account for this type of "alternate choice" uncertainty.

Should I pass the throw-away x parameter values in the sensitivity analysis?

Should I pass the discrete steel and aluminium values (that will be vectors entirely made up of 0s and 1s)?

Is there a third way I'm not seeing?

Comment: Would your model be used (by a decision-maker) *conditional on* these categorical choices? Offering more detail on the problem setting would help. I'm imagining that your model relates to some kind of engineering application, and that its purpose is to provide engineers with guidance on the effects of various design decisions they might make. But maybe I misunderstand?

Comment: @David I just added the context, which I had excluded because I was afraid of diluting the question. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: That's helpful. But I wonder at what stage of product design & manufacture the predictions from your model might be used. Since choice of materials would be a design choice *ex ante*, and a known characteristic of the product *ex post*, I wonder why you treat these factors as random variables.

Comment: @David This type of analysis is very data hungry, and good reliable data on everything is impossible to get. Assumptions are often made about e.g. material compositions. The sensitivity analysis should tell me whether the assumption on material composition is important: if highly sensitive, I should make sure I can specify what material is used, if not then concentrate on other sensitive parameters elsewhere in my model. In short, its about informing model refinement.

Comment: Ah, so the material composition of the manufactured product amounts to something like a *latent variable* into which you have limited insight even *ex post*? I still think you might do well to formalize the decision problem that your prediction model aims to inform. That way, you will force yourself to elaborate a utility (aka *loss function*) that clearly indicates what constitutes 'success' in your prediction modeling.

Comment: @David, great insight, thanks. But the question remains: should I integrate the samples of my (continuous) throw-away variable in my sensitivity analysis, or the (discrete and binary) material input samples? I have just run tests with Delta Moment Independent Measure implemented in the SALib Python library, and it doesn't balk at either. Perhaps the information generated by each approach is different. In the first case, its the sensitivity of not knowing, while in the second, its the sensitivity of including steel or aluminium, which are ultimately different things.

Comment: Now I appreciate your question much better. I would tend to understand your problem broadly in terms of *multiple bias analysis*; see the piece by Greenland that I cited in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/280849/41404). Under that doctrine, one ought to account for **all** sources of uncertainty in a prediction. So my answer to 1st part of your Q is: *Yes*. The 2nd part (whether to pass *x* or the dummy) seems like a narrower question about how best to obtain your Monte Carlo Standard Error (MCSE). Preserving *x* should be more efficient, if you can carry its info content thru.